# displaying an array in a jlist from a different class

Tags: java, arrays, class, jlist

i am trying to display the array i gave created in HobbyList and display it in ListView2, ant ideas?

hobbylist :
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Vector;

```
import javax.swing.JList;

public class HobbyList {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         //creating the array
         ArrayList hobbyArray = new ArrayList();

         //adding objects to the vector
         hobbyArray.add("Dancing");
         hobbyArray.add("Football");
         hobbyArray.add("Hurling"); 
         hobbyArray.add("Camoige");
         hobbyArray.add("Swimming");
         hobbyArray.add("Athletics"); 
         hobbyArray.add("Running");
         hobbyArray.add("Boxing");
         hobbyArray.add("MMA"); 
         hobbyArray.add("Tykwando");
            }
```

listview class:
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ListView2 extends HobbyList {


      public static void main(String[] a) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JList list = new JList(arl);

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood that you want to do from your code is to do something like this

HobbyList.java

```
public class HobbyList {

    protected ArrayList<String> hobbyArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public HobbyList() {
        hobbyArray.add("Dancing");
        hobbyArray.add("Football");
        hobbyArray.add("Hurling"); 
        hobbyArray.add("Camoige");
        hobbyArray.add("Swimming");
        hobbyArray.add("Athletics"); 
        hobbyArray.add("Running");
        hobbyArray.add("Boxing");
        hobbyArray.add("MMA"); 
        hobbyArray.add("Tykwando");
    }
}
```

ListView2.java

```
public class ListView2 extends HobbyList {

    public ListView2() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ListView2 lv = new ListView2();
        JList list = new JList(new Vector<String>(lv.hobbyArray));

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: just wondering would it be the same approach if i was to display them in a jcombo box

Comment: Yes, as [JComboBox Vector<> constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox(java.util.Vector)) explain, you can construct one from a Vector, so replacing JList for JComboBox should work just fine.

Comment: yes that worked perfectly also!  Any idea on how to do this? In each GUI provide a way to add to the HobbyList  and another button to refresh the list display. Keep 
the listener class(es) separate  to  the GUI classes  (the listener class\classes will  represent the controller\controllers).